# Mechanically securing PCB with imaging sensor

Tags: mechanical, mechanical-assembly

I designed a PCB with an imaging sensor that is mechanically coupled to a lens assembly using four 2-56 screws.  The lens/mechanical design realizes an image that is smaller than the imaging sensor (e.g. doesn't fill the entire sensor).  I'm noticing that even though the screws are holding the board tightly against the mechanical structure if I flick or lightly knock the the assembly the image "moves" (in other words the relative position of the lenses and imaging sensor changes).  I'm 99.99% certain that the lenses are not moving since they are adhered to the mechanical assembly.  If that's the case then it means that the board is moving around a bit.  The movement is ~40 pixels at most -- if each pixel is a few microns then we're talking about a very small mechanical movement, but something that's obviously very noticeable visually.  I'm hoping to get a few suggestions for ways to fix the PCB to the mechanical structure.  Any suggestions for adhesives or the like?  Something else?  Ideally I'd be able to disassemble the board from the mechanical structure (so dunking everything in epoxy isn't a great solution).

Comment: I am not sure, but if the image "returns to center" than it may just be a case of "rolling shutter".  It is a case of the timing the between when a pixel sensor moves the last frames image out and when it charges enough to take the next frame.  If you lift your device and move it "pan it" quickly from left to right, does it reproduce the issue? Without the "flick"?

Comment: Is there any recommendations in the datasheet?  Is there any minimum board thickness, or force/impact constraints?

Comment: Posting a picture or drawing of what you have would help.  Besides linear motion, it could also be tip/tilt of the lens relative to the plane of the sensor.  Take a look at how others have done the same task. (small CCD camera's)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It's definitely not a rolling shutter issue (it's a global shutter sensor and it doesn't return to center). No recommendations on the datasheet at all.  It's possible that it's a tip/tilt of the PCB, but not the lens.  The lens is effectively a part of the mechanical structure.  If it were tip/tilt then I'd expect an elongation/warping/defocusing, which I do not see.  I'd love to get my hands on a CCD camera and see what they've done. Maybe ebay will have a few cheapos.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add some mechanical stiffeners to your board. It may be too late for that, however, since that is usually factored into the PCB design (unless you want to design a new PCB and mounting fixture). The stiffener would be a rigid piece of metal or other material that runs along the length of your PCB (or sometimes across the center of it) with fasteners to hold the board tightly against it. It can also provide the mounting interface to your optics and/or thermal relief (heat sinc).

Comment: Interesting.  Any chance you have a drawing/photo of an example?  That seems like it might be a reasonable approach.

Comment: A quick google search yielded Teledyne's offering: http://teradynegso.com/node/177. You can find a number of examples with google images. You can get this sort of thing made at just about any machine shop and it looks like some are even 3D printing them. The hard part is making sure it doesn't interfere with anything on your PCB. usually you would deal with this by designing the PCB footprint in conjunction with the mechanical design of the stiffener.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an DSLR camera tear down for inspiration.
Here is a Nikon D600 by IFixit: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nikon+D600+Teardown/10708